# Calculated field taking into account a control in Looker Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I am working with a table looking like this:

| country | sales |
| --- | --- |
| USA | 250 |
| UKR | 150 |
| TOG | 100 |

Here is a [sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1flJnO7kKaiEBM2svOf7uQnfFhDL-o3QEyHlDcBxni78/edit?usp=sharing)

On my [page](https://lookerstudio.google.com/reporting/5d9d5edb-2808-48c1-994e-828b0890f9a7), I have a drop down that allow me to select counties, a map that displays the sales per selected country and I would like to add a pie chart that shows the proportion of sales from the selected countries (for example, if BEL+FRA+DEU+ESP are selected it should show ~19% (1900/9800))

I tried adding a field using SUM but I would need to be able to take contols / filters into account. I briefly explored blends but with no success so far ... What is the way of doing this ?

Comment: How often does the data update? If the total is fixed at 9,800 then there is a way to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by total being fixed at 9800? One can assume that the data does not move much (updated every quarter)

Comment: if it's acceptable to write a new formula each quarter then you can make a calculated like SUM(sales)/9800 so when the data was filtered then the value of that would be 19%. That could be put in a scorecard but if you want it in another type of chart what would it be?